# Split a string on 4 Numbers

Tags: string, vb.net, split, char, numbers

Given a string, for example,...

`1-23-4567 Apple Sauce`

I'm trying to figure out how to split that into

`1-23-4567
Apple Sauce`

My idea is to somehow split based on the 4 numbers at the end of the number sequence. I can't split on spaces. I've figured out how to split based on a single character...

`words2 = s2.Split(New Char() {"|"c})`

but can't seem to figure this out. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why you want to split that into the two strings `1-23-4567` and `Apple`? What is the logic behind? If you only want to take the first two "words" (delimited by space), then it's very easy. `s.Split().Take(2)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm sorry, mistyped. I want the number, and Apple Sauce. I added another word to Apple to make it clear I can't just split on spaces

Comment: Usually the real problem is that the fields aren't enclosed in quotation marks(csv files). Splitting on `4567` seems pretty strange. What if there is another number?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Every Entree will have "2-3 Numbers" - "2-3 Numbers" - "Exactly 4 Numbers". Thats why I want to split on exactly 4 numbers

Comment: I don't get it, your first token has only one digit: `1-2-4`. Comes anything after the `Apple Sauce` or is it always the end of the string?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes there will be more after `Apple Sauce`. But I don't see why that matters considering I am trying to figure out how to split on 4 numbers.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i'm reading about regex right now, is that an idea worth pursuing for this case?

Comment: @TimSchmelter guess another idea would be to split on the first occurence of a space

Comment: Of course it matters because your approach would be too complicated then. `Dim ix = s.IndexOf(" "c)
  Dim s1 = s.Remove(ix)
  Dim s2 = s.Substring(ix).Trim()`

Comment: If there comes more after `Apple Sauce`, for example `Apple Sauce and Bread`, what is the rule to find the delimiter `and`? Is there always a space between the second string? The rules aren't clear at all.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: words.Substring(0, t.LastIndexOf("-") + 4)

Comment: @Bob did you see my answer? Does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim r = New Regex("(\d+-\d+-\d\d\d\d )")
Dim m As String() = r.Split(s2).Skip(1).ToArray()
```

Make sure to `Import System.Text.RegularExpressions`

`s2` Is the imput string and `m` is the output array

Comment: @TimSchmelter I Just Tested It And It Works

Comment: Test it with a string like `"1-23-4567 Apple Sauce other stuff"`. How you ensure to get only two strings, `1-23-4567` and `Apple Sauce`? Your regex returns 3 strings, the first is empty, the second the number and the third is `Apple Sauce other stuff`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Isn't that what it is meant to do?

Comment: @BanForFun: the question isn't clear. I don't know if he wants to take the rest of the string after the first space, then it's easier with string methods. Or if he wants to take `Apple Sauce` and omit the rest, then it's not clear how he finds the end of the second string.

Comment: @TimSchmelter is overthinking things. I want two strings in the end. One being the number, one being whats left. I am currently testing Ban's solution

Answer (score 2):

> I want two strings in the end. One being the number, one being whats
>   left

So you want to split on the first space only? Then [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) has an overload to take only 2:

```
Dim tokens = s.Split({" "c}, 2)
```

Here's a sample and the result:

```
Dim s As String = "1-23-4567 Apple Sauce and other stuff"
Dim tokens = s.Split({" "c}, 2)
```

Result:

1. `1-23-4567`
2. `Apple Sauce and other stuff`

Another easy and efficient approach is to use pure string methods like `IndexOf` and `Substring`:

```
Dim spaceIndex = s.IndexOf(" "c)
If spaceIndex > 0 Then
    Dim s1 = s.Remove(spaceIndex)
    Dim s2 = s.Substring(spaceIndex).Trim()
End If
```

Comment: Bob says `My idea is to somehow split based on the 4 numbers at the end of the number sequence.` not on the first space.

Comment: @BanForFun: the reason why he thought he needed to split on 4 numbers was that he said that he can't split on spaces(because of the space between Apple and Sauce). But that's not true if he wants to take the remaining string after the first space.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Dim parts As New List(Of String)("057359-001 Pip Drt329 Auburndale, Fl (aub) - Pompano Beach, Fl (pob) 1:0 10gbe Lan Phy.".Split(" "c))
Dim myArr(1) As String
myArr(0) = parts(0)
parts.RemoveAt(0)
myArr(1) = String.Join(" ", parts.ToArray)
```

Comment: My issue here is I want two distinct strings that come from the split. The number, and the text. The text contains spaces so I can't split solely on text.

Comment: And how do you retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```js
          var target = "1-23-4567 Apple Sauce";

            var regEx = new Regex(@"\d\d\d\d"); //you are splitting on first 4 digit together
            var splitStrings = regEx.Split(target).ToArray();

            var stringItem = splitStrings.Last().ToString(); //This is "Apple Sauce"
 
            var digits = s.Substring(0, (s.Length - stringItem.Length)); //This is 1-23-4567
```